# SINR vs received power

Tags: wireless

Is the signal-to-interference-and-noise-ratio (SINR) always lower than the received power (P_r)? I mean, can I suppose that the SINR

Thank you so much for your help,

Best regards

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

SINR and received power are in different units, so it doesn't make sense to say one is less than the other.